# C buffer overflow prevention

Tags: c

I am new to programming and especially C programming. I am trying to learn C but I am really bad at it. Therefore, I hope that with all the gurus advise and guidance, I will be able to grasp it.

I have the following code ( but it faces buffer overflow concerns ) :

```
char buffer[1024];
int i=0;
char ch;

while((ch=getchar())!='\n'
{
 If (ch==-1) break;
Buffer[i++] = ch;
}
```

In order to stop the buffer overflow, can I do the following ?

```
const int BUFFSIZE=1024;
char ch;
int i=0;
while((ch=getchar())!=BUFFSIZE
{
 If (ch==-1) break;
 BUFFSIZE[i++] = ch;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. You say you want to learn C. 2. Your question title says C++. 3. You tagged the question C#.  Which one is it?

Comment: `BUFFSIZE[i++]`? BUFFSIZE is a **CONSTANT INTEGER**. You cannot redefine its value, much less use it as an **ARRAY**...

Comment: You have `const int BUFFSIZE=1024;` so therefore no, you can not use it like `BUFFSIZE[i++] = ch;`. Moreover, you have an error in your validation clause after the while in BOTH your versions - first, it has to be in between the brackets, second, it should look like this `while(ch=getchar() && i < BUFFSIZE`).

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: @EdHeal The OP clearly mentions that he is new to programming and C. Instead of being rude to him and deeming his question "not sensible" you could tell him where he's going wrong or suggest a book/tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

First off, your code doesn't even compile. It's `if`, not `If`. Your variable is `buffer`, not `Buffer`. You can't use an integer (`BUFFSIZE`) as an array...

Next, no, that is wrong.  You are testing the input character against your buffer size, which makes no sense. This is how you read a string and prevent buffer overflows in C:

```
char buffer[1024];
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
```

If you want to read character by character, ok, but you need to add a check for `i < BUFFSIZE - 1`, and you also need to null terminate your string (that's why you have the `- 1` in the check) assuming you want to use it as a string.

```
const int BUFFSIZE = 1024;
/* initialize each element to 0 to ensure that the result is null terminated */
char buffer[BUFFSIZE] = {0};
int ch;
int i = 0;

while((ch=getchar()) != '\n' && i < BUFFSIZE - 1)
{
   if (ch == EOF) break;
   buffer[i++] = ch;
}
```

Comment: Well, you can use BUFFSIZE[buffer] instead of buffer[BUFFSIZE], as indexing an array is an communative operator.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: What's you're point? You certainly cannot index into an int, which is what the OP has in his code. Your example would be relevant if `buffer` were an int.

Comment: Suggest `int ch` rather than `char ch`.

Comment: @chux: Yeah, good point.  I forgot even after changing `-1` to `EOF`.

Comment: @EdS. No, you're missing the point. If I have `char *a`, I can index into that array by doing either `a[1]` or `1[a]` - it's valid C code. Perhaps archaic, but in the standard.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I think it's you who is missing the point.  I understand perfectly well that `*(p + i)` is the same as `*(i + p)`.  What I don't understand is why you believe it to be relevant here. The OP's example has `BUFFSIZE[i++] = ch;`, where both `BUFFSIZE` and `i` are `int`s